# How do I use swiftlint to lint a single file?

Tags: swiftlint

I'd like to use swiftlint to lint a single file. How do I accomplish this?
Checking the docs on https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint was not helpful.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can also do this with:

```
swiftlint --path 'path to your file'
```

Comment: Yup, this is better than my way.

Comment: Please notice, `--path` flag is deprecated: https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/pull/3952

Answer (score 6):

```
SCRIPT_INPUT_FILE_COUNT=1 SCRIPT_INPUT_FILE_0="foo.swift" swiftlint lint --use-script-input-files
```

Comment: Docs don't talk about required 'lint' argument in a helpful fashion.

Answer (score 5):

To lint multiple files at once :

```
$ swiftlint -- file1.swift file2.swift
```